# @RetryableTopic @KafkaHandler and handling of unknown events

Tags: spring-kafka

I use spring kafka 3.0.12 and want to consume messages from a topic. I have a single `@KafkaListener` annotation on my consumer class and potentially multiple `@KafkaHandler` annotated methods, including one handling unknown messages.

My consumer code looks like below:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@KafkaListener(
  id="testListener",
  topics = "${kafka.topics.test.name}",
  groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}"
)
class TestConsumer {

  @Value("${kafka.topics.test.name}")
  private final String topicName;

  @KafkaHandler
  @RetryableTopic(
    backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000L),
    topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE,
    exclude = NotRetryableException.class,
    traversingCauses = "true"
  )
  public void consume(Test message) {
    ...
  }

  @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
  void consume(Object object) {
    log.error("Topic {} contain an unknown message: {}", topicName, object);
  }
}
```

Here is an extract of my application.yml configuration file. I use the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` and a custom function to handle the deserialization error when I do not receive a `Test` typed message:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      group-id: ${application.name}
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      properties:
        spring:
          deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
          deserializer.value.function: com.test.ErrorFunction # Custom function
          json:
            type:
              mapping: "Test:com.test.Test"
```

I know this code cannot work as the `@RetryableTopic` should be tied to `@KafkaListener` and the `@RetryableTopic` annotation are not processed in case of a [class level](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/8e76978e13a25af8939257acaa56d891d792acfe/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L398) `@KafkaListener` but only in the case of a [method level](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/8e76978e13a25af8939257acaa56d891d792acfe/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L391C11-L391C11) `@KafkaListener`.

My questions are:

- Is there a reason for not being able to configure a class level `@RetryableTopic` ?
- How to achieve the deserialization of my messages, handling unknown ones as I did with the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` and custom function and using retry topics without having to deserialize by myself in a single `@KafkaListener` and `RetryableTopic` annotated method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a reason ...

It was just not implemented - it's probably not too hard to do it; feel free to open a new feature request and we can take a look when we get time (or feel free to contribute a PR).

> How to achieve ...

I presume your custom function returns some object other than a `Test`.

One solution would be to have the function return a subclass of `Test` instead, and then you would just need an `instanceof` test in your single listener method.